# Start YouTube embed playlist at a specific video/index

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

My app generates the first YouTube url below and embed it. I would like to start the playlist at a specific video. It is possible to do so on non-embed link with the parameter index (see 2nd link below) but this parameter does not work for my embed link.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/uNDfgnWN2G0?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&playlist=IJrwmIQqj5s,uNDfgnWN2G0,pDf46hYF4CE

https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=uNDfgnWN2G0,IJrwmIQqj5s,uNDfgnWN2G0,pDf46hYF4CE&index=2

Is there an alternative url parameter I could use?

I tried the parameter start as well but it doesn't work with my playlist link if I want to go beyond the second video.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters